# Highcharts: how to dynamically update text inside of the label?

Tags: highcharts

I am having this code: https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/dk9zbsc1/5/ where I successfully can change the label's related colors and the font.

What I am missing is, I want to be able to update the text of the label itself.

I tried this with the code:

```
// Update the label
thischart.currentAnnotation.update({
  labels: [{
    text: fontText, //this line is not working         
    backgroundColor: fontBackgroundColor,
    style: {
      fontSize: fontSzie,
      color: fontColor
    }
  }]
});
```

And also I tried with the code:

```
thischart.currentAnnotation.labels[0].update({
  text: fontText
});
```

And a few more combinations which I found in similar threads (including the `attr` property), but none of them were working.

So I wonder, how can I update the text dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results from the fact that you have used `format` property in the label creation process and update `text` property. Text is overwritten by format.

```
    var onclick = function() {
        _self.chart.addAnnotation(Highcharts.merge({
                langKey: 'label',
                labelOptions: {
                    // format: labelTextForm.querySelector('#labelTextInput').value,
                    shape: 'rect'
                },
                labels: [{
                    text: labelTextForm.querySelector('#labelTextInput').value,
                    ...
                }]
            }, ...));
    };
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pghrfjsx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.format